# Averaging in Matlab while excluding NaN AND other specific values

Tags: excel, matlab

I have an Excel spreadsheet with columns of values that represent different variables in an experimental setup. For example, one column in my data may be called "reaction time" and consequently contain values representative of time in milliseconds. If a problem occurs during the trial and no value is recorded for the reaction time, Matlab calls this "NaN." I know that I can use:

```
data = xlsread('filename.xlsx')
reaction_time = data(:,3)
average_reaction_time = mean(reaction_time, 'omitnan')
```

This will return the average values listed in the "reaction time" column of my spreadsheet (column 3). It skips over anything that isn't a number (NaN, in the case of an error during the experiment).

Here's what I need help with:

In addition to excluding NaNs, I also need to be able to leave out some values. For example, one type of error results in the printing of a "1 ms" reaction time, and this is consequently printed in the spreadsheet. How can I specify that I need to leave out NaNs, "1"s, and any other values?

Thanks in advance,
Mickey

Comment: Might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586222/how-to-ignore-nans-in-matlab?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option for you might be to try [the standardizeMissing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/standardizemissing.html) function to replace the values that you want to exclude with `NaN` prior to using `mean` with `'omitnan'`.  For instance:

```
>> x = 1:10;
>> x = standardizeMissing(x, [3 4 5]); % Treat 3, 4, and 5 as missing values
x =
     1     2   NaN   NaN   NaN     6     7     8     9    10
>> y = mean(x, 'omitnan');
```

If you read your Excel sheet into a table, `standardizeMissing` can replace the values with `NaN` only in the column you care about if you use the `DataVariables` Name-Value pair.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, I got an error message upon trying to use the 'standardizeMissing' function. It reads "Undefined function 'standardizeMissing' for input arguments of type 'double'". As I'm fairly new to Matlab, I don't know what this means exactly. I'll keep trying, though.

Comment: `standardizeMissing` was introduced in R2013b, so if you have an earlier version you won't have access to that function.  A workaround to do something similar is to use `ismember`: `idx = ismember(x, [3 4 5]); x(idx) = NaN;`

Comment: Great. `ismember` got the job done. Thank you again for your help.